# Sed command to replace string that contains / and "

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a requirement where  I need  to read a XML file and replace the tag that contains `/`, `"` and save it as a new file.

The original tag format:

```
<CollateralReportDocument xmlns="http://schemas.foo.com/sII/CollateralReportDocument/1.0">
```

The new file should have the tag as:

```
<CollateralReportDocument>
```

I have tried using

```
Sed -i 's/<CollateralReportDocument xmlns="http://schemas.foo.com/sII/CollateralReportDocument/1.0">
/ <CollateralReportDocument>/g' filename.xml
```

...but it is not working. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Fixing your code that's reading the file to be namespace-aware would very much be the better practice. XML namespaces are there for a reason -- they're how/why a single document can have different types of (meta)data, and the people designing those schemas don't need to coordinate on a single set of names before someone can combine those schemas in a single document.

Comment: Even if you really do want to translate everything in the CollateralReportDocument/1.0 namespace to the default namespace, better to do that with an XSLT stylesheet, so it'll know that if you have a `xmlns:crd="http://schemas.foo.com/sII/CollateralReportDocument/1.0"` somewhere else in your document (or in a future version of same), `crd:bah` needs to be changed to `bah` in all parts of the document under the point in the tree where the definition took place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You use `/` as separator, but you also have some `/` inside your string to substitute.**

You should use `#` as separator instead.

**Linux:**

```
sed -i 's#<CollateralReportDocument xmlns="http://schemas.foo.com/sII/CollateralReportDocument/1.0">#<CollateralReportDocument>#g' filename.xml
```

**macOS:**

```
sed -i '' 's#<CollateralReportDocument xmlns="http://schemas.foo.com/sII/CollateralReportDocument/1.0">#<CollateralReportDocument>#g' filename.xml
```

Comment: command works without any error but the xml file still has the old tag the requirement is for Spark where I can not read this file at the root tag because the end tag is <CollaterlaReportdocument\>

Comment: @user2315840 Strange... It works for me on macOS and Manjaro. What OS/distribution are you working on?